# How to generate a .pem file for ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I've added my `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to my server's 'authorized_keys' file so I can do `ssh user@myserver -p port` and login to the server successfully. Yet when I do

```
ssh-keygen -f id_rsa.pub -m 'PEM' -e > id_rsa.pem
```

and then use

```
ssh user@myserver -p port -i key.pem
```

I got:

```
Load key "key.pem": invalid format
user@myserver: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

Comment: You have a PEM **public** key and are trying to login with it? You need a private key for that (and `ssh-keygen  -e -m PEM` always exports the public key)

Comment: Ops... Let me give it a try tmr. Sorry.

Comment: @muru You should post that as an answer, because... well, it's the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use PEM. I don't see why you would want to do that. Perhaps expand your question with some logic?

You should do:

1. ssh-keygen
2. ssh-copy-id user@server
3. ssh to server